# i want android override activity method in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I want `onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray)` method in fragment

I found google and anwser fragment

```
(mainActivity)getActivity.onrequestPermissionResult
```

but I don't know this parametor

Do you have any other way or know this parameter? All I know is requestCode

viewmodel

```
private val _permissionVisibility = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    val permissionVisibility: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _permissionVisibility
```

xml binding

```
 android:visibility="@{homeViewModel.permissionVisibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

mainActivity

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        Timber.d("Test ${requestCode} , ${permissions} , $grantResults ")

    }
```

Comment: get your fragment's instance in your activity and invoke the method you want in your activity

Comment: Add your code where you request for permission.Did you request permission in fragment or activity ?

Comment: I tried to do it too, but I couldn't do it because I didn't know the values ​​of the two parameters. is permissions , grantResults

Comment: Nam Trung  // request permission in viewmodel ,

Comment: @LeeDuSeop you should add all that you have done. It is easier to help. Your activity, fragment and viewmodel code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use new ***Activity Result APIs*** to get the result of permission and activityresult in much simplier way.
The Activity Results API provides two methods — **RequestPermission** and **RequestMultiplePermissions** . These two does exactly what their names are. Here’s a quick example code.

```
// Requesting Location Permission
bi.btnRequestPermission.setOnClickListener {
    askLocationPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
}

// Single Permission Contract
private val askLocationPermission = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { result ->
    if(result){
        Log.e("TAG", "Location permnission granted")
    }else{
        Log.e("TAG", "Location permnission denied")
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

// Requesting Mutliple Permissions - Location & Bluetooth
bi.btnRequestPermission.setOnClickListener {
    askMultiplePermissions(arrayOf(
      android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH
    ))
}
```

you have to add the following dependencies in your app’s build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha04'
```

Check the blog for reference- https://wajahatkarim.com/2020/05/activity-results-api-onactivityresult/

Comment: that last note "you have to add the following dependencies" is very important.